# How exactly are favorite rooms in the active tab sorted?

Tags: support, bug, chat

I have noticed that one of the rooms which I starred (favorited) does not appear in the correct place, when the favorite rooms are sorted by activity. It always appeared at the end.

I have started to do some more experiments. Sometimes the room appeared where they should be, sometimes at the end.

> Is active tab supposed to be working in this way?

---

I am adding two screenshots, showing that one room was always at the end, despite the fact that it has more recent activity than the room before it.

This is what I see on my second page of favorite rooms (the link in the browser is `https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=favorite&sort=active&page=2`):

[image: screenshot]

I have tried, as an experiment, adding a few more rooms. When I got enough rooms to have 3 pages of them, it looked like this:

[image: screenshot]

In both cases you can see that the room shown as the last one has more recent activity than the rooms before it.

Here is [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14886/room-for-balarka-sen-and-bolbteppa) to the room, which was always the last.

Comment: I have tagged this ([tag:bug]), but if this is the intended behavior, I will remove the tag.

Comment: Was the room created automatically?

Comment: Here is link to the transcript from the [first day of the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14886/2014/6/3). I do not see there any mention of the room being imported automatically from comments.

Comment: Yeah, just reproduced. Weird, no idea what's casing it.

Answer (score 8):

This is the intended behavior right now, but I can see how that's a bit weird in particular on the "favorite rooms" tab.

Most room sort orders put "special" rooms to the end of the list. Special rooms are

- those that were created through a "move comment discussion to chat" click (they're always called "discussion between A and B"), and
- those that were created by clicking a user and then "start a new room with this user" (they're always called "Room for A and B").

Moving those rooms to the end makes a lot of sense when you're on the (default) "all" tab – J. Random User looking at what kinds of rooms are available doesn't really care about those one-off, usually short-lived, rooms.

On the other hand when favorite rooms come into play, I agree that you're explicitly saying "I *do* care about this particular room". I can think of a few things that would be possible to do here:

1. Continue to put special rooms after general rooms, but put them before frozen and/or deleted rooms.
2. Continue to put special rooms after general rooms, *except* for those rooms that you have favorited.
3. Continue to put special rooms after general rooms on the "all" tab, but don't special-case them on the other tabs.

Neither of these change the apparent ordering for the "J. Random User" case above: 1. doesn't change it because frozen and deleted rooms are hidden by default on the "all" tab; 2. doesn't change it because we assume the user hasn't favorited anything, and 3. doesn't change it because it explicitly leaves the "all" tab unchanged.

I'm tending towards 1., because arguably frozen and deleted rooms are of even less general interest than special rooms. Note that 3. has the disadvantage that it would cause the main tab (i.e. the filter) and the sort order to no longer be orthogonal – sorting would behave differently depending on how you're filtering the rooms.

I'm open to opinions on this.

Comment: Thanks for the explananation. (At least I know why some rooms behave differently.) As far as possible changes are concerned, I am not sure, which would be the best possibility.

Comment: If I understand your options correctly then I favor #3 -- don't change anything for the "all" view, but ignore special status when sorting on the favorites list.  And frozen/deleted shouldn't automatically go to the end; for most people this doesn't matter, but moderators can see and might be monitoring such rooms.  Favorites sorted purely on last activity seems the most intuitive to this user.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Interesting, can you give a use case for monitoring frozen and deleted rooms? Nobody (except for moderators) can post messages there, so I don't see what's to monitor.

Comment: @balpha another use case I just realized I can offer: I have a (frozen) room that has a lot of useful-to-me stuff in it, such that I refer to it from time to time, but it's otherwise outlived its purpose.  I have that favorited so I can find it when I want it.  Since it's inactive I expect it to fall to the bottom of the list, of course.  (It doesn't currently, because it wasn't auto-generated.)