# Sort "favorite" chat rooms by strict recent activity rather than by type of room

Tags: feature-request, chat, favorite-rooms

Right now I find that I often can't find, even when I've added them to my favorites. According to [this answer by balpha from 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234142/284336), this sorting is intentional because there are two "types" of rooms - normal rooms and "special" rooms:

> Most room sort orders put "special" rooms to the end of the list. Special rooms are
>
> - those that were created through a "move comment discussion to chat" click (they're always called "discussion between A and B"), and
> - those that were created by clicking a user and then "start a new room with this user" (they're always called "Room for A and B").

So... there's a problem with this assumption - it's *easier* for me to make a chat room by clicking "start a new room with this user" than to go and find the other way to create a room. They may *start out* being titled "Room for A and B" but they don't *have* to be titled that. When I have a long list of rooms - both active and inactive - on my favorites (which I do), it ends up being sort of random which rooms are which. Let's look at my favorite rooms (some info hidden):

[image: Screenshot of "Favorite" chat rooms]
(Click to enlarge)

So, there are a couple of things going on in this image... I have some frozen/deleted rooms (greyed background) and I have at least one room that starts with the "Room for A and B" format that's in the first grouping of "normal" rooms, rather than in the grouping of "special" rooms. I suppose it's possible that I mimicked the titling of the other rooms for talking with someone specific. I don't remember.

The room towards the end with the arrow pointing at it was last active twelve hours ago **and** it has a custom room name - one I picked myself. I did start it by choosing a user in chat and creating a room with them but I did that out of expediency, not because of any conscientious choice that the room was somehow "special". Sometimes, finding the "create a room" button is difficult and, until I found balpha's answer, I didn't realize the rooms were treated differently dependent on how they were created.

I view rooms that are "start a new room with this user" to be quite different from "move this discussion to chat" rooms. Particularly as a moderator, I've found that these rooms are often little used but may be revisited several times over. I'd rather the former be grouped with the "normal" rooms than the "special" ones, if I had my preference. But, short of that, on the "Favorite rooms" tab, **can we please sort absolutely by time, ignoring the method of room creation**?

This is something that balpha hinted at they were considering anyway, back in 2014:

> 1. Continue to put special rooms after general rooms, but put them before frozen and/or deleted rooms.
> 2. Continue to put special rooms after general rooms, except for those rooms that you have favorited.
> 3. Continue to put special rooms after general rooms on the "all" tab, but don't special-case them on the other tabs.

Option 1 would help me somewhat, as I do have frozen/deleted rooms but it still wouldn't bring the rooms up above relatively inactive rooms if the special rooms were recently active.

Option 2 would be fine with me, though it might be more complicated? I like this option, as it would make these rooms appear on all of the tabs if they were recently active.

Option 3 would also be fine. I usually visit rooms from my favorite tab anyway, because my favorite rooms span a wide variety of sites, so looking only at site rooms isn't very useful.

Comment: Also... could we please fix [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145927/chat-room-list-layout-changes-when-zooming-out)? As you can see from my screenshot, it's still a bug that's happening and it's been five years.

Comment: Regarding the other bug, SE does not support zoom, several developers said that over the years. No idea why they didn't reject it yet, but I'm 100% they will at some point.